# Your device isn't compatible with this version - Note Pro 12.2

Tags: android, google-play

one of my client reported that he cannot install on his device Note Pro 12.2

[image: device is not compatible]

I checked on my developer settings that I allow for all device to install.

[image: all devices allow]

[image: Note Pro 12.2]

Anyone have any ideas why this happen ?

Manifest :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
```

Comment: Permissions shouldn't be an issue.  There's no uses-* or support-screens sections?

Comment: nope. but i use this : `<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true" />`

Comment: Ok, I found the problem here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17267986/nexus-7-compatibility-issue  Apparently there is a permission problem-  the telephony permission makes Google require you to have a telephony stack.  So unless your tablet has 3G, it won't be compatible.  Add required="false" to that permission

Comment: Yah, that could be it. thank you for the pointer.