# Your device isn't compatible with this version in Asus Nexus 7-inch tab

Tags: android, android-screen-support, uses-feature

I developed my app for only Tablets. It was working fine previously but playstore app is not even listing my app on Nexus 7-in Tablet after recent update of my app. On playstore website it's showing the message -"Your device isn't compatible with this version". I'am able to see and download my app on 10-in Tablet. On developer console the Nexus7 is listed there as compatible.

These are the permissions and features added in my manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />   
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"/>

<supports-screens android:smallScreens="false"
                  android:normalScreens="false"
                  android:largeScreens="true"
                  android:xlargeScreens="true"
                  android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600" />
```

Please guide me why am'i getting this message.

Comment: I think it's the problem of Play Store .

Comment: What can I do from my end to fix this issue?

Comment: Refer this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17267986/nexus-7-compatibility-issue?rq=1

Comment: have you added screenshots under Tablet-7 inch?

Comment: yes i added the screenshots for 7 inch also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use android:required="false" for your

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"/>
```